# For what variables these equalities are satisfied?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, optimization

Assume: 
$$
P \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,N\},\quad |P| = K, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}_+^K , \qquad w = e^{-j\frac{2\pi}N}
$$
Consider:

$$
h_{P,X}(l) = \sum_{i=1}^K \sum_{j=1}^K x_ix_jw^{(p_i-p_j)l}
$$
Now suppose we want to find $(P,X)$'s that satisfy:
$$
h_{P,X}(1) = h_{P,X}(2)= \cdots = h_{P,X}(N-1)
$$
Do you have any suggestion ?
>
If for simplicity we manually set $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_K = cte$ the problem could be solved in this way :
$$
f_P(l) = \sum_{i=1}^K \sum_{j=1}^K w^{(p_i-p_j)l} = \sum_{d=0}^{N-1} a_d w^{ld}
$$
where $d = p_i-p_j \mod N$ and $a_d$ is the number of occurrence of $d$. As you know $a_0 = K$.
The last term is telling us that $f_P(l)$ is FFT of signal $a[d]=a_d, d=0,1,\cdots,N-1.$
Now suppose we want to find $P$'s that satisfy :
$$
f_P(1) = f_P(2)= \cdots = f_P(N-1)
$$
Also it is easy to show that: $f_P(0)=\sum_{d=0}^{N-1} a_d=K^2$.
This means that we have FFT of $a_d$, so calculating $a_d$ is easy, and having $a_d$, we could find $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete solution right now, but I have an observation.

Note that $$\large h_{P,X}(l)=\sum_{j=1}^K\sum_{j=1}^Kx_ix_j w^{(p_i-p_j)l}=|f_{P,X}(l)|^2$$ where $$\large f_{P,X}(l)=\sum_{i=1}^Kx_i w^{p_il}$$ So $\large h_{P,X}(l)=c\ \forall 1\le l\le N-1 \Rightarrow f_{P,X}(l)=\sqrt{c}\ \forall 1\le l\le N-1,\ c>0.$

Comment: Thanks for your attempts, But I knew this before! and I changed the $f$ to $h$ hoping to be more convenience.